# ElasticSearch query fields in disabled object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic Search 6.8.7 cluster.

I have a column with this mapping:

```
"event_object": { "enabled": false, "type": "object" }
```

I want to search for records that match certain other criteria, and also have a particular value for a particular field field in this object.

So far, I have tried variations of doing a normal search for the indexed fields, and a filter script for the unindexed ones:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        "query_string": {
          "query": "foo:bar"
        }
      }, 
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc[\"event_object\"][\"state\"].value == \"R\""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "terminate_after":1000, 
  "from":0,
  "size":1000
}
```

Which is a hodgepodge of testing myself forwards based on google searches.  But I can't get things to even compile, let alone run and filter.

Comment: Why `enabled: false` for a field which is to be used in search criteria? Using script has performance impacts? If possible remove `enabled: false` for `event_object` field and re-index documents.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant its not something I control, my queries are relatively rare, and its a very big document that was made disabled because of previous write performance issues.  All I want is to be able to filter the results and I'll be fine.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to access the content of JSON objects that have `enabled: false`. From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html):

> Elasticsearch skips parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be retrieved from the `_source` field, but it is **not searchable or stored in any other way**

So even scripting will not help here.

However, there's one way to access this disabled data from scripting in a `terms` aggregation (using the `include` parameter and a `top_hits`sub-aggregation):

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "state": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "params._source.event_object.state",
        "size": 100,
        "include": "R"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you'd get a response like this one:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "state" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "R",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "test",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "event_object" : {
                      "state" : "R"
                    },
                    "test" : "hello"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```